# Unable to install custom folder from GitHub in Symfony vendor folder

Tags: symfony, github, composer-php

I want to install particular folder from GitHub in my Symfony project in vendors folder. For that in `composer.json` I have given the path:

```
"require": {  
  "vivekssharma07/api-library": "^2.12"
}
```

And in GitHub the package which I want to install has in `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "vivekssharma07/api-library"
}
```

Error what I am getting is:

> Problem 1   The requested package vivekssharma07/api-library could
>   not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:   A typo in the package name   The package is not
>   available in a stable-enough version according to your
>   minimum-stability setting

Comment: *there may be a typo in the package name* . Did you cross checked the package name.

Comment: Did you registered `vivekssharma07/api-library` package at Packagist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've not submitted your fork to packagist you will need to specify the GitHub location in the `repositories` section  of the `composer.json` file in your Symfony Project i.e.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:vivekssharma07/api-library.git"
    } 
]
```

Comment: Now i have registered my package with Packagist but the problem is when i run that composer require the content inside the folder is different...I am getting the content from which i have forked my local changes is not reflecting ?? Do you the reason ?? (I forked a project from some repo and in local i made some changes and commited it and then i uploaded it in packagist but the changes are not reflecting)

Comment: I got the solution i am forking it from some repository thats why its taking  contents of that forked repository..Is there any alternate way to get my own changes from forked repo.

Comment: One more question is there if you could answer .. Now if i run composer require xyz/api-library so i'm getting minimum-stability error in Packagist its showing dev-master..how should i configure dev-master in composer.json